# @csrf_exempt stopped working in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

I have the following code, that was working fine in Django 1.2.5:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

class ApiView(object):
    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        method = request.method.upper()
        return getattr(self, method)(request, *args, **kwargs)

@csrf_exempt
class MyView(ApiView):

    def POST(self):
       # (...)
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps(True), mimetype="text/javascript")
```

But when I upgraded to Django 1.4, I started to get a 403 forbidden, with a "CSRF verification failed" message.

Why is that @csrf_exempt decorator not working?

URL definition is:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^myview/(?P<parameter_name>[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/$',
       views.MyView(),
       name="myproject-myapp-myview",
       ),
)
```

Comment: Note: Calling a view this way is not thread safe. You should create a new instance for each call.

Comment: Could you please give the url definition for the view??

Answer (score 22):

According to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-the-class):

> To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate
>   the class definition itself. To do this you apply the decorator to the
>   dispatch() method of the class.

So you'd need to do something like:

```
class MyView(ApiView):

    def POST(self):
       # (...)
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps(True), mimetype="text/javascript")

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Since poster uses POST in capitals, i don't think he's using django class based views

Comment: @william- Good catch.  This answer doesn't apply then.

Comment: yes, I'm not using the django class based view. I`m very sorry that I missed that MyView is a callable, as ApiView implements __call__ (I`m mantaining someone else's code). So, this class is a callable, and the @csrf_exempt on the class used to work in django 1.2, but does not in 1.4.

Comment: This wouldn't work anyway, even for class-based view.  Per the docs, you have to wrap the csrf_exempt decorator in the method_decorator decorator: `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)`

Comment: Finally. THANK GOD. That was bloody complicated. Thank you for providing an answer that actually works.

Answer (score 12):

Just use `csrf_exempt` in the `urls.py`. ie::

### urls.py

```
..other imports...
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt   
from myapp.views import MyView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^myview/(?P<parameter_name>[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/$',
       csrf_exempt(MyView.as_view()), # use csrf_exempt here
       name="myproject-myapp-myview",
       ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

csrf_exempt has to decorate a function. In your urls you can decorate a that function, [docs can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf).

```
(r'^vote/', permission_required('polls.can_vote')(VoteView.as_view())),
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I hadn't noted an important fact: this class is a callable.  I just updated the question.