# Using Django-Angular to make a AJAX call to a view

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I'm trying to use Django-Angular to make a AJAX call to a view in Django. I'm following this  guide [here](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dispatch-ajax-requests.html).

However, when I make a POST I'm getting the message: **CSRF verification failed. Request aborted**. It seems like the `action` as described in the [docs](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dispatch-ajax-requests.html#dispatching-ajax-requests-from-an-angularjs-controller) `process_something` isn't being called as I shouldn't need the token.

Can anyone spot the issue, **below is what I have tried so far**...

**Here is the relevant js controller script:**

```
   var in_data = {action: 'process_something', somevar: $scope.somevar};
   var post_call = CbgenRestangularDjango.all('pin-verification/').post(in_data)
```

**and the form:**

```
<form ng-controller="PinValidationFormCtrl"  name="CompanyValidPinForm" class="bs-callout">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input class="form-control" name="somevar" ng-model="somevar" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitPin()">Verify Pin</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

**and the view:**

```
class VerificationView(JSONResponseMixin, View):
    # other view methods

    @allowed_action
    def process_something(self, in_data):
        # process input data
        out_data = {
            'foo': 'bar',
            'success': True,
        }
        return out_data
```

Comment: @Stewie I think the question is  clear, and you can see what I have already tried. I'm unsure why you posted your comment, please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: Have you setup angular app as specified [here](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf-protection.html)?

Comment: yep @mariodev I have :). I have Django-Angular working for normal GET requests, but for some reason it's not calling process_something function in the view on POSTs being made, and I think this is why I have the message about CSRF as  [@]allowed_action is not being run.

Comment: Does the POST request work when you decorate `process_something` method with `@csrf_exempt`? (If decorating class-based view's method with `csrf_exempt` doesn't [work](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15794), try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10252521/1432478))

Comment: a (firebug) screenshot of the attempted post request would also be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The `post()` method accepts a config parameter to pass the `X_CSRFTOKEN` header:

```
var config = { headers : { 'X_CSRFTOKEN' : $cookies.csrf_token }};
var in_data = {action: 'process_something', somevar: $scope.somevar};
var post_call = 
CbgenRestangularDjango.all('pin-verification/').post(in_data, config);
```

In your view's template the form must include the token as follows:

```
<form ...>
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

Note `$cookies` depends on `ngCookies` (see [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookies](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.%24cookies))

Answer (score 4):

You must pass the csrf token when sending a HTTP POST request.

Include `{% csrf_token %}` in your form or add a custom header `X-CSRFToken`. This should work.

Answer (score 3):

Its most likely you are missing a header in your angular's app module config.

Try setting the following

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
});
```

> Django applications do not require this header, but if it is missing, all invocations to: `request.is_ajax()` would return False, even for perfectly valid Ajax requests

Found here: http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html 
Also there was an api change at angular version >= 1.1.x (this header default was dropped since that version). Perhaps Django did not catch up with their documentation in every part.

---

*Maybe* you just need to clear your browser cache as you might have an outdated cookie sending an invalid token letting the request mapping fail.

Comment: Did you try this? I deleted this answer for some days but I am still curious if this can be the problem so I reactivated it.

Answer (score 2):

you can also try/use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator

-->  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt

and here's the Django documentation of how to apply it to class based views =)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views